# Tasty - Who am I?

Tags: riddle

There was a green house.
Inside the green house there was a white house.
Inside the white house there was a red house.
Inside the red house there were lots of babies.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It is

> **watermelon**

There was a green house.

> it have green layer outside

Inside the green house there was a white house.

> inside green layer there is slightly white layer

Inside the white house there was a red house.

> watermelon's pulp is red

Inside the red house there were lots of babies.

> There are lots of seed in that pulp.

> [image: Picture of a watermelon]

Answer (score 10):

Tasty - guess who am I?

> An attractive pregnant woman carrying octuplets. [Tasty](http://thefreedictionary.com/tasty) has the meaning of 'attractive' when referring to women.

There was a green house.

> The pregnant woman was wearing a green dress.

Inside the green house there was a white house.

> Her underwear were white in colour.

Inside the white house there was a red house.

> Two ways to justify. Either her skin was red, or the redness refers to the viscera inside her body.

Inside the red house there were lots of babies.

> Her children in her womb. God bless them!

Comment: I prefer to think of the 'white house' as her skin and the 'red house' as her viscera.

Answer (score 6):

My first thought:

> A Tomato (or its seeds, depending on which bit the "I" refers to)

The green house

> Is a standard gardener's glass green house

Inside the green house

> There is a white refrigerator

Inside the white house

> There is a freshly-plucked tomato

Inside the red house

> Are lots of tomato seeds (babies)

Comment: Why would there be a refrigerator inside a greenhouse?

Comment: a. To keep the tomatoes fresh once picked (or to chill seeds to stratify them before sowing).   b. Because the puzzle demands a "white house" :-)   A white cool

Comment: Are greenhouses kept warm? That just increases the work the refrigerator must do to keep things cool.

Comment: I never claimed it would be _sensible_ to put fridge in greenhouse...

Answer (score 4):

> To differing degrees all of these have a green shell, followed by white and red layers, and being fruits, they all contain seeds.
>  Fig: [image]
>
>  Papaya: [image]
>  Guava: [image]
>  Guayaba: [image]

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the obvious answer by @CoDe MurDeRer, here is alternative:

> Really big and color-specific Matryoshka doll

There was a green house.
Inside the green house there was a white house.
Inside the white house there was a red house.
Inside the red house there were lots of babies.

> The outermost layer is green, next is white and red. An because it is a big one, it will have lots of "babies".